# Direct upload to Azure blob storage using Plupload

Tags: azure, plupload

I am trying to use [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com) to directly upload to Azure blob storage. From what I understand Azure requires a PUT request for uploading a file to a blob storage and Plupload only supports POST requests. Is there a way to setup plupload to make a PUT request? Or alternatively is there a way to upload directly to Azure using a POST request?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Azure Storage JavaScript Client Library for Browsers](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/tree/master/browser) can help you. Here is a [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-javascript-client-libraries)